# Controlling the Mc's of a loaded SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I have a controller.swf which loads an external swf into a movieclip.

news_mc = loadEvent.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;

the swf is called "news.swf" and has a movieclip on the maintimeline, frame 1 called "sb".

I have tried everything to access this such as

mews_mc.sb.alpha = 0;

but nothing works?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
news_mc['sb'].alpha = 0;
```

are you sure the news_mc and news_mc['sb'] are not null?